# applescript choose file title

Tags: applescript, finder

I have got a `choose file` in my applescript. How do I change the title of the `Choose a File` window that comes up. I am aware of `with prompt`, but it doesn't change the title.

**Edit:** ulvund answered *I'm afraid with prompt is the best you can do*, but are there any other ways to get a `choose file` without applescript? Also, are there any hacks?

**Edit 2:** Red_Menace answered (look below) but are there any good tutorials on how to do this in Cocoa-Applescript?

P.S. Look at my comments.

**Edit 3:** [I have put this into another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125563/cocoa-applescript-nsopenpanel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog in plain AppleScript doesn't have that option, but you can access various Cocoa methods in Snow Leopard and Lion using AppleScriptObjC.  In Lion, you can create a Cocoa-AppleScript Applet from the template in the AppleScript Editor, then create your own dialog, for example using [NSOpenPanel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid **with prompt** is the best you can do:

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as309.html

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the edited question: You can use Automator.

`Ask for Finder Items` action in `Files & Folders` library will show the choose file dialog. You can *change the title* of the dialog of this action.

Comment: i would use automator, but you can't do an `if` in the `Run Applescript` and then do an automator action. Or can you?