# Reference external script file

Tags: applescript

I'd like to implement [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532681/applescript-choose-file-or-folder) (also listed below) as a separate file. How do I formulate the reference to it as a POSIX path?

```
tell application "ASObjC Runner"
    activate
    set chooserResult to run the script {chooseFilesOrFolders} with response
    -- the above line would have to reference something like RemoteVolume/test.scpt
end tell
```

The referenced script itself existing as separate file "test.scpt":

```
script chooseFilesOrFolders

    tell current application's NSOpenPanel's openPanel()
        setTitle_("Choose Files or Folders") -- window title, default is "Open"
        setPrompt_("Choose") -- button name, default is "Open"

        setCanChooseFiles_(true)
        setCanChooseDirectories_(true)
        setAllowsMultipleSelection_(true) -- remove if you only want a single file/folder

        get its runModal() as integer -- show the panel
        if result is current application's NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton then error number -128 -- cancelled
        return URLs() as list
    end tell

end script
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the fFinder path for your script test.scpt, and then call the library using "load script file" command:

In your test.scpt file :

```
 On ChooseFilesOrFolders
 -- all your script lines here
return URLs() as list -- to send back result of your sub routine
end ChooseFileOrFolders
```

In your main script :

```
Set Script_Lib to "HD:Users:me:Desktop:test.scpt" -- the complete path to your text script.

Set My_Lib to (load script file Script_Lib)

-- insert here you main script lines, and when you want to call the function :
tell My_Lib to Set chooserResult to ChooseFilesOrFolders
-- Here, chooserResult will contain the list returned from test script
```

Also note that your script "test can also contains many other subroutines which can be called as fonctions in your main script.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you pbell, this clarifies the methodology. It works with plain vanilla script but I can't get it to work within the "ASObjC Runner" construct... I'm not sure if  `run the script {chooseFilesOrFolders} with response` is the culprit...