# Apple Script for zipping a dropped folder without .DS_Store

Tags: macos, terminal, zip, applescript

I need a "PC friendly" way of zipping folders with files via Drag'n'Drop. The problem ist that the person receiving the archives can't either save or extract them if these contain ".DS_Store" or "__MACOSX" files.

Following existing examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178288/apple-script-for-zipping-a-file) I couldn not succeed in doing the following:

- Create an AppleScript droplet that zips dropped files or a folder by preserving the file structure inside that folder
- Using the macOS zip binary to exclude ".DS_Store" and "__MACOSX" files

What I can do is in Terminal:

`zip -r myArchive.zip * -x "*.DS_Store" -x "__MACOSX"`

But said command only works when cd'ing to that folder first and then using the wildcard together with the exclude parameter to compress "anything except"

How can I do this in AppleScript?

Current non working version:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return fileZipper(item 1 of input)
end run

on fileZipper(thisItem)
    set tPath to thisItem as text
    if tPath ends with ":" then
        set oTid to text item delimiters
        set text item delimiters to {":"}
        set tPath to text 1 thru text item -2 of tPath
        set text item delimiters to oTid
    end if
    set zipFile to (tPath & ".zip") as text
    do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of tPath)
    do shell script "/usr/bin/zip -r " & quoted form of POSIX path of zipFile & " * -x \"**/.DS_Store\" -x \"**/__MACOSX\""
    return zipFile as alias
end fileZipper
```

Comment: Each instance of `do shell script` resets the environment, so you can't `cd` in a separate `do`. Try `do shell script "cd (to wherever) ; zip (whatever)"`. The semicolon instructs the shell to complete the prior command before beginning the subsequent one. You can test the resulting dir with something like `do shell script "cd ~/Desktop ; pwd"`

Comment: Per the man page, this is the structure of the command: `zip options archive inpath inpath`. You're using `*` for 'inpath' which is why you need to cd to the correct dir. If you ran `zip -r myArchive.zip ./Desktop/other/  -x \*.DS_Store \*__MACOSX` then it should create myarchive.zip in the home folder and fill it with the contents of 'other' on the desktop, while excluding unwanted files.

Comment: Thank you, @Mockman! I currently have the script set to not using the wildcard as you suggested, but the resulting zip still contains .DS_Store. The string that gets sent to the shell is : `/usr/bin/zip -r '/Users/mischa/Downloads/TestArchive.zip' '/Users/mischa/Downloads/TestArchive' -x '.DS_Store' -x '__MACOSX' `

Comment: I think that your quoting should be fine. However, without the wildcard, I don't think it will find those unwanted files (in order to exclude them), i.e. it's looking for a full path but you're only providing the name. It should exclude those files when they're in the top level of your directory (i.e. TestArchive) but not when in subdirectories. Try `'*.DS_Store'`.